# Separate character to only number

Tags: r, web-scraping, split

I tried to split column message between "เริ่มต้นที่ : ฿ 675" to only "675" price number column. But it dosen't work.

You can see df. In this link below df and website url.

df before I tried to separate:

[image]

website: https://fitwhey.com/

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)


url <- "https://fitwhey.com/"

brans <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements("span.p-name") %>%
  html_text2()

price <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements("span.p-sale-price") %>%
  html_text()


price <-str_split(price, "[ก-๙]+")


rank_seller <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements("span.number") %>%
  html_text2()


df<- data.frame(rank_seller, brans, price)
```

Comment: You could try `stringr::str_extract(price, "[0-9]+$")` or `gsub("\\D+", "", price)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also `parse_number()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"https://fitwhey.com/" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_elements(".product-list") %>% 
  map_dfr(~ tibble(
    rank = .x %>%  
      html_element(".number") %>% 
      html_text2(), 
    brans = .x %>% 
      html_element(".p-name") %>% 
      html_text2(), 
    price = .x %>% 
      html_element(".p-sale-price") %>% 
      html_text2() %>% 
      parse_number()
  ))

# A tibble: 20 × 3
   rank  brans                            price
   <chr> <chr>                            <dbl>
 1 1     MY WHEY PROTEIN                     54
 2 2     MEGA MASS PRO 1350                 291
 3 3     100% CREATINE 5000                 375
 4 4     ISO - PRO                          850
 5 5     L-CARNITINE X500                   638
 6 6     BAAM GOLD WHEY PROTEIN              68
 7 7     BAAM CREATINE 5000                 375
 8 8     BAAM CUT                          1125
 9 9     BAAM MASS 2600                     249
10 10    REAL WHEY PROTEIN                  978
11 11    FITSOY 100% SOY ISOLATE            525
12 12    BAAM MY WHEY PROTEIN THAI SERIES    54
13 13    CLA XTREME 1500                   1125
14 14    100% GLUTAMINE 6000                638
15 15    CLEAN MASS HI-PROTEIN GAINER      1660
16 16    BAAM ZMA                           600
17 17    LEAN WHEY HERS                    1785
18 18    HULK MASS GAINER 1500             1079
19 19    ANGEL BURN-9                      1125
20 20    BAAM HYDRO WHEY                   2250
```